# How to show ticks and subticks on zerolines in QCustomPlot?

Tags: qt, qcustomplot

Is there any way of showing ticks and subticks over zerolines in QCustomPlot? I couldn't find anything in documentation.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author by mail?

Comment: Your question is limit *unclear*. QCustomplot is not a widely used library, and you did not provide images of "what I am able to do right now" and "what I would like to do".

Comment: It is widely used libaray among QT developers and I did found the tag 'qcustomplot' in stackoverflow as well. Anyways I will contact the developr.

Comment: I never used it for plotting, and there are only 21 questions with this tag as we speak. Either someone had the same issue to help you, either he will need to dig deep. Providing different images are a good starting point. Note: I didnt downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create ticks and subticks with QCPItemLine. Here is the code:

```
for(int i=-65; i<=65; i+=10)
{
    // Ticks
    QCPItemLine *tickHLine=new QCPItemLine(ui->customPlot);
    ui->customPlot->addItem(tickHLine);
    tickHLine->start->setCoords(i,-1);
    tickHLine->end->setCoords(i,1);
    tickHLine->setPen(QPen(QColor(137, 140, 140), 1));

    //Subticks
    QCPItemLine *subTickHLine=new QCPItemLine(ui->customPlot);
    ui->customPlot->addItem(subTickHLine);
    subTickHLine->start->setCoords(i+5,-2);
    subTickHLine->end->setCoords(i+5,2);
    subTickHLine->setPen(QPen(QColor(137, 140, 140), 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have your layers mixed up. Make sure your grid is on a layer below the axis, because the zero line is part of the grid, and the ticks part of the axis. So for example:

```
axis->setLayer("axes");
axis->grid()->setLayer("grid");
```

Note that "axes" and "grid" are layers that exist by default. And normally the grid is already placed on the correct layer, so what you are experiencing is probably due to clearing the default setup/plot layout and then creating a new axis rect all on one layer.